# mojolicious route->via->to vs post | get -> to

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I'm trying to understand mojolicious routing a little better.

Can someone explain the difference between using something like

```
$r->route('/register')->via('get')->to('auth#register')
```

as opposed to

```
$r->get('/register')->to('auth#register')
```

or are they exactly the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well spotted - they are the same.

`get` is a shorthand for `route->via('get')`. `via` is set up to restrict a route to particular methods (e.g. `GET` or `POST` or both). It might appear redundant, but consider how often you're likely to have a `get()` route in your Mojolicious app...